# Delete clips from a video while retaining multiple audio tracks

Tags: video-editor, editing

I have some videos (MP4 or MPV format) that contain muliple language audio tracks (English, French and Spanish). **I want to cut out some clips** (usually 15-60 seconds at a time) that I feel are inappropriate for my young children, **but I want to retain the multiple audio tracks**, since I try to immerse my kids in these three languages.

The only commercial video editor I have is Camtasia Studio, but it seems to support only one language track (please correct me if I'm mistaken). I don't want to pay for another video editor just to do this one task. I'm looking for a solution that a free editor can do. I run Windows 8.1.

I would appreciate any pointers. I don't need step-by-step instructions; a recommendation for a suitable editor plus just very high-level instructions should be sufficient. I am willing to convert the video format if necessary to do the job (e.g. using Handbrake).